# c# - Transparent form doesn't show text properly

Tags: c#, forms, text, controls, transparency

The idea of my project is to show solid text on a transparent form control.

I have used this technique to make the form transparent:

```
BackColor = Color.Lime;
TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;
```

The problem I'm having is coloured edges around the text. I've tried drawing anti-aliased text using graphics and displaying the text using labels but neither worked. I still have disgusting-looking, pixelated, lime edges around my text.

I looked around a little - posts are usually concerned with making the form transparent not dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can get *reasonable* output by using `TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit`.

```
private void TestForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
  e.Graphics.DrawString("Header", this.Font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1, 1));
}
```

But if you plan on using large fonts, it won't render too well since it can't really *antialias* properly.

The nature of fonts, in general, is to have a background to draw on.  If you have black text on a transparent form, and the end user has a black background-- the end user isn't going to see anything.

Comment: Yup.  Did you mean small fonts?